# Digest authentication on Azure WCF Worker Role

Tags: authentication, azure

I was wondering how to implement Digest Authentication on a Azure WCF Worker Role.
This being my Azure Worker Role I'm a bit confused how and where to configure this.

Anyone got a good blogpost on authentication with Azure?

Answer (score 1):

First, to specify WCF configuration in a worker role, I believe you would have to do it programmatically as opposed to using a config file, similar to this sample:  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/CSAzureWCFWorkerRole-38b4e51d/sourcecode?fileId=21645&pathId=708564178

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MessengerService));
Binding binding = ...;
host.AddServiceEndpoint(..., ...binding, url, ...);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(...);
```

Secondly, Digest authentication seems to require an AD infrastructure / windows domain per this reference: 
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738318(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738318%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

It wasn't clear from the question whether this worker role gets explicitly added into windows domain.

Comment: Hi Simon, I understand the working of WCF and configuration is done programmatically. I've got a WFC Worker Role running on Azure. I'm specifically interested in the implementation of authentication. How is it done, what to configure, what to code.

Answer (score 0):

Ralf,

In absence of IIS & AD infrastructure you would probably need to provide a custom digest authentication implementation for WCF and there aren't too many samples available on this.

The article below seems useful - it shows how to do it for WCF REST service but the code might be reusable.
You only need to consider any security implications of reusing 3rd-party code for this purpose.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162726/Digest-Authentication-on-a-WCF-REST-Service

-Simon.